# ActionResult returning a Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My `ActionResult` returns a `File` but I also need it to conditionally return a `Stream`.

I have not been able to find documentation on how an `ActionResult` can return a `Stream`.

Here is my code for return of a file:

```
    return File(memoryStream,.... )
```

As mentioned, I need to return just a `Stream`.

Comment: The file is being streamed to the client, no?  What does the stream buy you?

Comment: I have an ActionResult calling and Actionresult. The second Actionresult needs to send a Stream to the first action result which will then be changes to a file which is not stored on file.

Comment: Your question is confused. You're not returning *"a `File`"*, you're returning a `FileStreamResult` using [a helper method called `File()` that takes a `Stream` and returns a `FileStreamResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_6). You've already got the answer to your question in your existing code, and the accepted answer is just a slightly longer syntax to do the same thing!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Updated for MVC5 2020:

*my previous answer was dated.*

as of now, the `File` returns different type of ActionResult depends on given arguments

```
// to return FileStreamResult
return File(memoryStream, "application/pdf");
// or..
return File(memoryStream, "application/pdf", "file_name");
```

---

Use [`FileStreamResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.aspx):

```
MemoryStream stream = someService.GetStream();

return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks. Also curious, is it possible to return just a stream without it being associated with say pdf. Meaning, just return a stream

Comment: @NatePet You could use `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: -1; this is a bit confused, although I had to delve into the docs to realise it. The OP's existing code - calling [`Controller.File` with a stream as the first argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_6) - is *already* generating a `FileStreamResult` under the hood. You're just proposing a more verbose syntax for what the OP's code already did!

Comment: Is the stream closed if exception happens before File result line is called? so like

MemoryStream stream = someService.GetStream();
//some error throwing line here...
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf")

Answer (score 9):

Having an action call another action is a design smell. You should avoid it. Simply put the logic that needs to be reused between the 2 actions in a service layer. And then call this logic from your 2 actions.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Action1()
{
    Stream stream = service.GetStream();
    // ... do something with the stream and return a view for example
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Action2()
{
    Stream stream = service.GetStream();
    // let's return the stream to the client so that he could download it as file
    return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```

Now you no longer need to call the second action from the first one.

Answer (score 8):

The shortest way to use a `Stream` as the result of an Action Method in a `Controller` is the one you already showed in the question: use the [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx) helper method of `Controller`. This returns a [`FileStreamResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.aspx).

There are a couple of overloads available that take a `Stream`. Both overloads require the MIME type of the response to be specified, which will be emitted as the `Content-Type` header of the response; if your circumstances are such that this is unknown to your application, you could always specify [`text/plain`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1) or [`application/octet-stream`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1) for arbitrary text or binary data, respectively. One overload additionally takes a third parameter that sets the filename to show in the browser's download dialogue (controlled via the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header), if applicable.

**Overload signatures**:

```
protected internal FileStreamResult File(
    Stream fileStream,
    string contentType
)
```

and

```
protected internal virtual FileStreamResult File(
    Stream fileStream,
    string contentType,
    string fileDownloadName
)
```

**Example usage**:

```
return File(myStream, "application/pdf");
```

or

```
return File(myStream, "application/pdf", "billing-summary.pdf");
```