# How to return a generic memory stream from ASP.NET Core (in my case an embedded resource stream)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a json file as an embedded resource, and I'd like to return this file from a `GET` endpoint.

I have no luck with figuring out how to return a generic stream, I've tried the following but it returns an empty body:

```
[HttpGet("KpiClasses")]
public Task GetKpiClasses(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var assy = typeof(ManagementReportManager).Assembly;
    var resourceName = typeof(ManagementReportManager).Namespace + ".KpiClasses.json";
    var stream = assy.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);

    if (stream is null)
        throw new Exception("stream == null");

    Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Response.Body = stream;

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

There is of course the `File` function (`FileStreamResult`) but I want to just return the response as a plain json object as-is so that does not seem the way to go about things..

How can I return a C# stream from an ASP.NET Core endpoint?

Comment: Hmmm, the first thing that comes to mind is: Read the data to a string and send back the string with the apllication/json header (since you're sure the stringified data is a valid json). Could that be a viable solution? Or, parse your data file from json into an object and then send the object back from the endpoint (however, in that case, you would be wasting CPU cycles on decoding/encoding something that's already a valid json)

Comment: The `File` method does exactly what you want. `return File(stream, "application/json");` and change your return type to `IActionResult`.

Comment: *"I want to just return the response as a plain json object"* - This suggests deserializing the stream, and then returning the object instance to be reserialized, which is pointless and wasteful if the embedded file is exactly what you want in the response.

Comment: @TDiblik you're right - but this question is about just returning a stream, ignoring the fact that there is json in that. This is the case for me me but i'm wondering how i could just return a memory stream with arbitrary text.

Comment: @madreflection it may be that the File method is exactly this, however i'm not really sure - I want this endpoint to behave just like i would return a normal json object. I'll do some testing later with this.

Comment: @sommmen oh, sorry! I've searched for a bit in my own code and every time I wanted to send back a stream I have used the File method. I've also came across, [this answear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984181/16638833), which seems to suggest that File does indeed return a stream (at least in newer net versions).